# Can't execute javascript after jQuery .load(

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've seen some similar problems solved here but I wasn't able to find a solution yet.

I have a .NET MVC project, and on some pc I can't execute javascripts after a .load() call.

I have:

- a page RealtimeAlarms
- an ascx component AlarmsList
- a javascript file Alarms.js

RealtimeAlarms loads all the js needed, and render the ascx component using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/Alarms.js") %>"></script>
....
....
<input type="text" id="Like" />
<img alt="Filter" src="<%: ResolveUrl("~/Content/Images/Search.png") %>" class="clickable" onclick="FilterAlarms()" />
....
....
Html.RenderAction("AlarmsList", "Alarms", new {Like = ""});
```

Alarms.js looks like this:

```
function FilterAlarms() {

    var data = {};
    data.Like = $('#Like').val();

    $("#AlarmsDiv").html("");
    $("#AlarmsDiv").load(BaseUrl + "Alarms/RealtimeAlarms #content", data, function  (responseText, textSatuts, XMLHttpRequest) {    });
}

function ShowUsers(id)
{ 
   ....
}
```

My RealtimeAlarms components:

```
foreach(var alarm in ViewData.Model)
   { %>
    <li onclick="ShowUsers(<%: alarm.Id %>)"><%: alarm.Description %></li>
<% } %>
```

When I first load the page it always works nicely.
ShowUsers() always works.

My problems begin when I hit Filter.
FilterAlarms() always returns the correct list.
On some pc ShowUsers() stops working, it's not even invoked anymore.

Using the same browser (I tried with Chrome and IE9), on some pc ShowUsers() always works fine, and on some other pc it stops working after FilterAlarms().
Using the same datas.

Thanks to all for any suggestions.

Comment: Are there any errors in browser's console?

Comment: is javascript not enabled on the pc's that it does not work on?

Comment: Javascript is enabled. Everything works fine until I filter.

Comment: I've not noticed any error in browser's console.